GooglePlacesAutocomplete onpress event not working
During the text change, I can see all the suggested addresses that means the key is working as expected, however when I select and pressed the item nothings happen. The data did not show even I tried any hardcoded printed value.

`const handlePlacePress = (data, details = null) => {
  console.log('Place pressed:', data);
  console.log('Place details:', details);
};

return (
  <View style={styles.searchBarContainer}>
    <GooglePlacesAutocomplete
      placeholder="Search location"
      onPress={handlePlacePress}
      query={{
        key: 'process.env.PUBLIC_MY_KEY',
        language: 'en',
      }}
    />
  </View>
);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  searchBarContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    alignItems: 'center',
    paddingHorizontal: 30,
    marginTop: 15,
    backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
    elevation: 5,
    borderRadius: 20,
    width: '70%',
    alignSelf: 'center',
  },
});`

Here is the setup from my google account. I enable the following API library:
-Places API
-Geocoding API
any suggestion why the onPress event did not trigger. Thanks in advance!
I want to see something when I press on the suggested address.

Have you tried putting the code inside handlePlacePress just inside the onPress callback? As the example on the package shows. Does that work?

same thing, nothings happened

Do you see any error or log?

no error shown from my designer and web console
